# Set Value in a field that has a default value of "0.00" set on it already

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

I am calling the setValue function on a particular field, however the field has a default value of "0.00" set on it. Now what happens is the value that I pass in with the setValue function is appended to the '0.00'

Answer (score 0):

Just call clearValue on the field before you setValue to it. [clearValue](http://nightwatchjs.org/api#clearValue) clears a textarea or a text input element's value.

```
browser
 .clearValue('input')
 .setValue('input', '123')
```